# Things to keep in mind while overriding hashCode

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
    private String name, comment;
    private int age;

    public Person(String n, int a, String c) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        comment = c;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Person))
            return false;
        Person p = (Person) o;
        return age == p.age && name.equals(p.name);
    }
}
```

> What is the appropriate definition of the hashCode method in class Person?
>
> A. return super.hashCode();
>   B. return name.hashCode() + age * 7;
>   C. return name.hashCode() + comment.hashCode() / 2;
>   D. return name.hashCode() + comment.hashCode() / 2 - age * 3;

The answer is *B*.

Can someone explain, why C and D are wrong?

Comment: You could use any of those hashcode methods (A might not give good results), but B is the simplest one.

Comment: @JonasCz C and D are wrong because they're not consistent with equals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For A, C and D, `hashCode()` might return a different result for 2 instances of `Person` whose `equals()` method returns `true`, i.e. two `Person`s that are equal might return different hash codes.

This clearly violates [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--)'s contract:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

For C and D, if two `Person`s had the same age and name but different comment, `equals()` would return `true`, while `hashCode()` would produce different values.

For A, as `Person` implicitly descends from the `Object` class (i.e. it doesn't extend from any explicit superclass), the result of `super.hashCode()` would be equal only when invoked on the same instance. According to `Object.hashCode()` docs:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)

So, if you had two different instances of the `Person` class, both with the same name, age and comment, `equals()` would return `true`, while `hashCode()` would return different values, violating `hashCode()`'s contract.

In practice, this means that the `Person` class could not be the key of any `Map`.

Answer (score 4):

The equals method says that objects are equal when they have the same name and age. The comments don't affect equality here.

The contract of equals and hashCode requires that 2 equal objects have the
same hashCode.

C and D can violate this rule because objects with the same name and age, but different comments result in different hashCodes.

Answer (score 2):

From cursory reading. It seems B is the better one because of the `equal()` method  take account of those two variables (which is name and age).